# I can't display the name of the user when I connec my app with Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I'm trying to make a facebook login for my app to connect with facebook, everything went good, I created a login page added an imageView to show the user facebook's profile photo, a label to display the name of the user, I managed to display the image of the user when I loged in to Facebook, but I couldn't connect the name's label to the code to display the user name! can anybody help please ?  This is my code :

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: FBSDKProfilePictureView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }
    else
    {
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self

    } 
}

// Facebook Delegate Methods

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    println("User Logged In")

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work
        }
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    println("User Logged Out")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            println("fetched user: \(result)")
            let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
            println("User Name is: \(userName)")
            let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
            println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
        }
    })
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the code in the debugger, is userName getting set to the user's name? I don't see anywhere in your code where you're actually setting the UILabel nameLabel's text to your userName var.

Could you provide some more detail? If this was simply an oversight, the problem is you need to set nameLabel's text to userName.

```
nameLabel.text = userName
```

If this wasn't an oversight and userName is not getting set to the proper value of the user's name, you're most likely doing something incorrectly in the Facebook SDK.

Comment: but if I'm able to get the facebook profile pic of the user why I can't get his name ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you figured this out yet, but I was having the same problem I had the profile pic displaying but not the username. Anywho I just added the last line 'self.' to your code and it worked:

```
let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
            print("Username is: \(userName)")
            self.nameResult.text = userName as String
```

swap 'nameResult' for your labels name 'nameLabel' and that should work.